# Hibernate CreateNativeQuery return empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am using Hibernate and JPA in my project. I use below code to return list of objects but it return empty list when i use sql in mysql it's worked correctly.

```
Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery("select tools.* from tools where (SELECT DATEDIFF(:user_date,calibDate) AS DiffDate) < :diff",Tools.class);
    query.setParameter("user_date",userDate);
    query.setParameter("diff",day);
    return query.getResultList();
```

anybody can help to spot what is wrong?

Comment: Check your parameters. Are they what they should be?

Comment: yes my parameters is what i want i debug that.

Comment: Try removing `Tools.class`, debug it and check if something is returned

Comment: @I.G.Pascual That will be of no use. Instead you should enable query logging, and see what the actual query is that is sent to the database.

Comment: @Kayaman, if there is a fallback when hibernate cannot serialize to the giving class, then you're right

Comment: Can you enable `show_sql` and paste the query that is getting fired?

Comment: @BandiKishore I think `show_sql` doesn't print the parameters converted to values, only `:user_date`, etc...

Comment: @I.G.Pascual If the query returns something, but it can't be mapped to a `Tools` instance, an exception will be thrown. It won't be silently ignored.

Comment: @Kayaman I use hibernate, no JPA, and it always fallbacks to a Map of values

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Not when you're using a `TypedQuery`. Besides, Hibernate is a JPA implementation, so there's absolutely no difference in the functionality.

Comment: Thanks to all. userDate is type of Localdate in java 8 i change it to util.Date and it works correcctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery("select tools.* from tools where (SELECT DATEDIFF(:user_date,calibDate) AS DiffDate) < :diff",Tools.class);
    query.setParameter("user_date",userDate, TemporalType.DATE);
    query.setParameter("diff",day);
    return query.getResultList();
```

TemporalType.DATE should be added to the 'user_date' parameter